# C++ OutputIterator post-increment requirements

Tags: c++, iterator, post-increment

C++ requires that an OutputIterator type `X` support expressions of the form `r++`, where `r` is an instance of `X`. This postfix increment must be semantically equivalent to:

(*)  `{ X tmp = r; ++r; return tmp; }`

and must return a type that is convertible to `X const&`. In C++11, see 24.2.4 (this is not new, however). In the same section, it says

> > Algorithms on output iterators should never attempt to pass through the same iterator twice. They should be *single pass* algorithms.

Given (*), above, say I copy the return value like `X a(r++);`

1. Suppose `r` was dereferencable before incrementing, but was not dereferenced. Is it required that `a` be dereferencable? If so, must `X a(r++); *a = t;` perform the same assignment as `*r++ = t;` would have otherwise? Are there any (other) conditions on `a` and `r` ?
2. Otherwise, suppose `r` was dereferenced/assigned before incrementing, and its incremented value is (also) dereferencable. Which of the following (if any) are well-defined: (a)
   `*a = t;`,  (b) `++a; *a = t;`, (c) `*r = t;`?

---

Also see the follow-up: [Dereference-assignment to a doubly incremented OutputIterator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11887104/985943)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you note, `r++` has operational semantics

```
X operator++(int) { X tmp = r; ++r; return tmp; }
```

I've added the return value as `X` because per 24.2.2:2 `Iterator` satisfies `CopyConstructible`, so it is legitimate to copy construct the return value of `r++` into an instance of type `X`.

Next, `*r++ = o` is required to be valid; this differs from `{ const X &a(r++); *a = o; }` only in the addition of a sequence point, which merges with the sequence point after `return tmp;` in the *operational semantics* definition above, so the compound statement has the same validity as the expression statement.  By invoking `CopyConstructible`, `{ X a(r++); *a = o; }` has the same validity and operational semantics.

In the case

```
*r = o;
X a(r++);
```

the following hold:

- (a) `*a = o` is invalid because that value of the iterator has already been dereference-assigned;
- (b) `++a; *a = o` is invalid because that value of the iterator has already been incremented, violating the single-pass requirement, as only (the new value of) `r` is required to be incrementable: per the note to 24.2.4:2, *Algorithms on output iterators should never
  attempt to pass through the same iterator twice*, although it's not specified what *pass through* means in this context;
- (c) `*r = o` is valid, because the only difference to `*r = o; r++; *r = o` overall is the continued existence of a copy of the original value of `r`, which per `CopyConstructible` requirements has no semantic effect on the value copied from.

Another interesting question is (for a non-dereference-assigned `r`):

```
X a(r);
++r;
++r;
*a = o;
```

This isn't covered by the standard directly, but from `CopyConstructible` it appears it should be valid.

Comment: I've asked a follow-up [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887104/dereference-assignment-to-a-doubly-incremented-outputiterator).

Comment: Part of my motivation for this question was the *multi-pass guarantee* [24.2.5:3], which OutputIterators need not offer. This guarantee includes the clause that `(void)++X(r),*r` must be equivalent to `*r`. Is it possible for `r++`, as specified above, to return an `X` that, when dereferenced, will point to the 'wrong' element (because `++r` modifies some data structure that `tmp` also references)? Or is this impossible, (perhaps) because of the validity of `*r++=o` and the operational semantics of `r++`?

Comment: Actually I am no longer sure that this answer is 100% correct, in light of our discovery here: (http://stackoverflow.com/q/11887104/985943). Namely, defect 2035 (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2035) now specifies "After [`++r`]
`r` is not required to be
incrementable and any copies of
the previous value of `r` are no
longer required to be dereferenceable
or incrementable." So it's unclear to me what you *can* do with `a` (from `X a(r++);`)

Comment: @nknight what's particularly interesting is the new operational semantics for `*r++ = o : { *r = o; ++r; }` combined with the existing operational semantics of `r++`; the problem is that `r++` *is* a copy of a previous value and yet must be dereferenceable; interposing an extra copy (as either `*X(r++) = o` or `X tmp(r++); *x = o` cannot change that requirement.